# Rails models validation on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot figure out why my model is not behaving as I want.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates :first_name, :last_name, 
               presence:true, 
               length: { maximum: 30 }
    validates :username, 
              presence:true, 
              uniqueness:true, 
              length: { maximum: 30 }
    validates :password, 
               presence:true, 
               confirmation: true, 
               length: { :minimum => 6}, 
               unless: lambda{ persisted? and password.nil? }
    validates :password_confirmation, 
               presence: true, 
               unless: lambda{ persisted? and password.nil? }
    validates :email, 
               format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }, 
               uniqueness: true, 
               allow_blank: true
 end
```

As you can see the code is quite easy.

To have a password_digest field I neeed both 'password' and 'password_confirmation'.

In create mode everything is fine.
In update mode is not working as I need.

I want to check validate the password and check if they match always, except when the user already exist and the 'password' field is null.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you define "not working as I need" for us?

Comment: Just a guess, but you might have a typo here: `persistent?` should probably read `persisted?`

Comment: About the first comment, if you see I defined that just the line below the one you quoted. The second was a type error, in the code I have 'persisted?'

Comment: Yes, you described the desired result. My question was about what actually happens.

Comment: It the password is null (and is persisted), it does not check. That's fine. 
But if the password is present and the password_confirmation is null, it doesn't check as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a simpler logic:

```
validates :password, 
          presence:true, 
          confirmation: true, 
          length: { :minimum => 6}, 
          unless: :persisted?

validates :password_confirmation, 
          presence: true, 
          if: lambda{ password.present? }
```

For a new `User`:

- if `password` is blank, you get an error on `password`
- if `password` is present and `password_confirmation` is blank, you get an error on `password_confirmation`

For an existing `User`:

- if `password` is blank, nothing happens
- if `password` is present and `password_confirmation` is blank, you get an error on `password_confirmation`

Comment: The error was into the controller, the model was fine, sorry if you waste time. 

It worked my logic, anyway I prefer the style you proposed. Thanks a lot

Comment: @FrancescoE. thanks for the update, and glad to hear you found the issue.